# When is an orthogonal projection a unitary operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:
When is an orthogonal projection $P: \Bbb C_n \to \Bbb C_n$ a unitary operator?

Thoughts:
I thought about using the fact that the only eigenvalues for projections are 1 and 0. Don't really know how to use it though..

Comment: Again this question? Just yesterday it was around...!

Comment: I wish the search algorythms in this site would have been better...

Comment: Oh, @user16 : we'd all wish many thinga be better in this site, among other what you mention, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\operatorname{rank}(P)<n$, $\operatorname{rank}(PP^*) \le \operatorname{rank}(P) < n$ so $PP^*\not= I$

If $\operatorname{rank}(P)=n$, $P=I$ so $PP^*=I=P^*P$

Comment: The first case is moot as a projection is always invertible, and the second case automatically assumes what, imo, *must* be proved, namely: $\;P=I\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio: "a projection is always invertible" O_O.

Comment: $P^2=P$ and $P$ invertible trivially imply $P=I$.

Comment: Great answer. actually rk(PP*)=rk(P) isn't it?

Comment: @user1685224 : Yes because an orthogonal projection is self-adjoint so $PP^*=PP=P$.

Comment: That was supposed to be "orthogonal projection" in my comment: I swear over my sweed Teddy Bear's grave I thought I wrote that...